# Update Field On Click of OutputLink in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, outputlink

I have a link referencing one contact record in Visualforce page. On click of the said link, a number field from `Contact` object must be equal to 1. But field is blank each time I click the link.

Meanwhile, here are the apex class and the visualforce page:

**Apex Class**:

```
public with sharing class OutputLinkController {

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
    private Contact contact {get;set;}
    public Integer viewCount {get; set;}

    public OutputLinkController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        this.controller = controller;
        this.contact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();

    }

    public void processLinkClick() {
        viewCount = 1;  
    }

}
```

**Visualforce Page**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="OutputLinkController">  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputLink value="https://ap7.salesforce.com/0032800000R4Cz3">
            Contact record
            <apex:param name="viewCount"
                value="{!contact.Record_View_Count__c}"
                assignTo="{!viewCount}"/>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Modified Apex Class**:

```
public with sharing class OutputLinkController {
    public Contact contact { public get; private set; }

    public OutputLinkController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.contact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference UpdateClickCount() {
        UpdateContact(contact.Id); 

        return new PageReference('https://ap7.salesforce.com/?id=0032800000R4Cz3AAF'); 
    }

    @future 
    public static void UpdateContact(Id contactId) {

        Contact c = [SELECT Id, Record_View_Count__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0032800000R4Cz3AAF'];

        c.Record_View_Count__c = 1; 

        update c; 
    }
}
```

**Modified Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="OutputLinkController">  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateClicks" action="{!UpdateClickCount}" />

        <apex:outputLink value="#" onclick="UpdateClicks();">John Doe</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I don't believe apex:outputLink supports apex:param. Also, how do you expect processLinkClick to be called? You're not calling it anywhere.

Comment: In the [`apex:param` docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm?search_text=outputLink) it does say it supports `apex:outputLink`, but I dont think its meant to be used like this. Are you trying to track the number of clicks on this link, starting with the number stored in the contacts field?

Comment: @sfdcfox `processLinkClick` is supposed to be tied on `apex:outputLink` but looks like `action` is neither supported in `outputLink`.

Comment: @curdual Try a commandLink, instead?

Comment: @battery.cord The aim is to assign a fix value of 1 to `Record_View_Count__c` field on the very first click. I am not necessarily tracking the number of clicks on this link.

Comment: Well, I wrote something to do that. It can pretty easily be adapted, so Im going to post it anyway (why write something & not post it anywhere?)

Comment: @sfdcfox Have been thinking of that also. But the requirement is to update `Record_View_Count__c` field using the existing `apex:outputLink` tag. So that's a bit of a challenge on my end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took the liberty of rewriting your component.

It seemed like you were trying to update the value of the contacts field by 1 when the link is clicked, and were starting out by setting the value directly to one.

To run an action for components that don't support the `action` attribute, you need to define an `apex:ActionFunction`, and set up an event listener, ie, `onchange`. All this does is create a javascript function which runs some apex when you call it.

We create a action function, and set it to `UpdateClickCount` when the `ouputLink` is clicked. This actually doesn't work at all, unless you set the `value` attribute to an anchor (`#`). The page changes/refreshes before it can actually run the javascript & apex.

So instead of having the `outputLink` redirect the user, the `onclick`'s `action` returns a `PageReference` with the contacts id. It also sets up a `@future` method to update the record in another context, instead of waiting for the dml to complete before redirecting the user.

Not exactly what you were looking for, but I'm sure you can adapt some part of this for use with your code.

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="OutputLinkController">  
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateClicks" action="{!UpdateClickCount}" />

        <apex:outputLink value="#" onclick="UpdateClicks();">{!Contact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Class

```
public with sharing class OutputLinkController {
    public Contact contact { public get; private set; }

    public OutputLinkController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.contact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference UpdateClickCount() {
        UpdateContact(contact.Id); 

        return new PageReference('/' + contact.Id); 
    }

    @future 
    public static void UpdateContact(Id contactId) {
        Contact c = [SELECT Id, Record_View_Count__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :contactId];

        if (c.Record_View_Count__c == null) {
            c.Record_View_Count__c = 1; 
        } else {
            c.Record_View_Count__c += 1;
        }

        update c; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But what exactly does `This actually doesn't work at all, unless you set the value attribute to an anchor (#).` this statement mean? Does it mean I have to put my sample url in the `value` attribute? My apologies if I didn't get it right.

Comment: If the `value` is a valid url, you'll be redirected to the new page before your javascript/apex in your `onclick` can load (it wont even get a chance to run a future method, and you cant set an actionFunction to point at a @future method). There might be another way around this, the code above is just how I wrote it. Since your return was a hard coded contact id, I assumed it was a test id, and set page up to redirect to the contact id. You'd want your hard coded url to be specified in the `pageReference` returned from `UpdateClickCount` instead of the contact's id like how I wrote it.

Comment: I've added my modified code on my original post. When I preview the page, there's no link displayed, though I made sure that both url and record id are correct.

Comment: Add `?id=003...` to your url. You're still using the standard controller, so there needs to be an id in the url or it won't know which record to use. You could avoid the whole thing by replacing `{!Contact.Name}` with some static value, if the names empty, even if the code would work, the link has no body & wont be visible. Tripped me up too when I was testing earlier

Comment: Wow! it is working now! I've added `?id=003...` to the url in the controller, and placed a static value in the visualforce page in the meantime. When I retested it, the field updated to 1 :)) Now I get the idea. Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Your page url should look like `/apex/OutputLinkPage?id=0030000000`. The url in the controller is fine, its the url on the page that needs an id parameter to fetch information about the record on the page. If you don't need the standard controller to get your record info, its probably not worth using on the page.